# Glassfish GET JSON web service 500 error - MessageBodyWriter not found

Tags: java, json, glassfish, jersey-2.0

I am getting

> > MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.HashMap$Values, genericType=java.util.Collection

from a web service with Glassfish 4.1.  Everything I see says to have the jackson or other library in the classpath so that the types can be converted.  With Glassfish, I have:

```
~/apps/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs$ find ../../../../ | grep jackson
../../../../glassfish/modules/jackson-core.jar
../../../../glassfish/modules/jackson-annotations.jar
../../../../glassfish/modules/jackson-databind.jar
../../../../glassfish/modules/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider.jar
../../../../glassfish/modules/jackson-jaxrs-base.jar
../../../../glassfish/modules/jersey-media-json-jackson.jar
```

Entity Classes:

```
public class Actor extends AbstractBaseEntity{
    public Actor(String id, String name) {
        super(id, name);
    }
}

public class AbstractBaseEntity {
    String identifier;
    String name;

    public AbstractBaseEntity(String id, String name){
        this.identifier = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
@Path("actors")
public class MockActorService {
    private static final int DEFAULT_COUNT = 5;
    HashMap<String, Actor> items;
    public MockActorService() throws WFlowServiceException {
        this(MockActorService.DEFAULT_COUNT);
    }

    public MockActorService(int actors) throws WFlowServiceException {
        items = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < actors; i++) {
            Actor a = new Actor("ID:" + i, "Actor Name " + i);
            items.put(a.getIdentifier(), a);
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAll() throws WFlowServiceException {
        GenericEntity< Collection< Actor > > entity;
        Collection<Actor> vals = items.values();
        entity = new GenericEntity<Collection<Actor>>(vals){};
        return Response.ok(entity).build();
    }
}
```

Why am I still getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Glassfish has Jackson, but it also has [MOXy](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy), which is the default provider. MOXy is weird with some types. If you want to disable MOXy so you can use Jackson, you need to set the following property to `true`

> [`ServerProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE)

I haven't used Glassfish in a while, so I am not sure if you will still need to register Jackson, but I'm pretty sure you don't. It should be automatically registered. MOXy basically blocks it from being registered.

Comment: Where do I set this property?  I looked for ServerProperties in all the files under glassfish and cannot see where to set it?

Comment: If you are using only standard JAX-RS APIs, then you can just use the String version of the property. Click the link to see. You can configure properties in an Application subclass by overring `Map<String, Object> getProperties()`. Or in your web.xml just use an init-param.

Comment: Otherwise, if you have Jersey dependencies, and you are using a ResourceConfig subclass, you can call `property(key, value)` in the subclass constructor. For any more help, I would need to know more about your set up.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some digging, I came up with the following to fix it.  @peeskillet was partially right, and this fix is Glassfish specific.

[Here is the blog with more context](http://blog.mikeski.net/blog_post/449)

Here is what fixed it.  I needed to implement the following 2 classes:

```
public class JacksonFeature implements Feature {

    Logger L = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JacksonFeature.class);

    @Override
    public boolean configure(final FeatureContext context) {
        String postfix = "";

        postfix = '.' + context.getConfiguration().getRuntimeType().name().toLowerCase();
        context.property(CommonProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE + postfix, true); 

        L.info("Set property to true disable MOXY: " + CommonProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE + postfix);
        context.register(JsonParseExceptionMapper.class);
        context.register(JsonMappingExceptionMapper.class);
        context.register(JacksonJsonProvider.class, MessageBodyReader.class, MessageBodyWriter.class);
        return true;
    }
}

@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("api")
public classMyResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    publicMyServicesResourceConfig() {
        register( new GZipEncoder() );
        register( JacksonFeature.class );
        addMyResources();
    }

    private void addMyResources() {
        register( Service1.class );
        register( Service2.class );
    }
}
```

Comment: You could've made your life easier by just telling more about your set up, as mentioned in my last comment. I didn't want to post every possible way which would be pointless. In your post, you have some stuff here that is not needed, for one, because there is already a JacksonFeature in the `jersey-media-json-jackson` dependency, which you could register. If you wanted to keep the fix standard JAX-RS, I could've also helped you with that. But I didn't know how you were structuring your app; around Jersey? around standard JAX-RS? web.xml? Java config? etc. That's what I meant by "set up"